# Get key from a value in python and use the key instead of a value for performing any operation

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def file_reader():
        config_dict = {}
        configParser = configparser.ConfigParser()

        configParser.read('config.ini')
        for section_name in configParser.sections():
                for (each_key, each_value) in configParser.items(section_name):
                        config_dict[each_key] = each_value
                config_dict = dict(configParser.items(section_name))
                list_vals = list(config_dict.values())
                list_keys = list(config_dict.keys())
                return config_dict
def main():
        config_dict = file_reader()
        for k,v in config_dict.items():
                print(k, "=", v)
        parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='start script', action='store_true')
        parser.add_argument('-q', '--stop', help='stop script', action='store_true')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.start and args.stop:
                print("error")
        elif args.start:
                for k,v in config_dict.items():
                        subprocess.call([v], shell=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I have developed this script. I can get the keys and values and successfully execute the script. Right now only the values are being looped over and executed by subprocess.call. How can I just use the key which has the result instead of the value and use it in subprocess.call?

Comment: "How can I just use the key which has the result " - what result? If you just want the key use [k] instead of [v] inn the loop

Comment: The key is just a variable name and subprocess won't be able to run the command

Comment: what result do you want to use instead of v?

Comment: So for example my config file is as follows 
'[my-config]
path1 = "/home/asad.javed/stop-services.sh"
path2 = /home/asad.javed/script.py
path3 = /home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0
`
I just want to use the key instead of value in subprocess to execute the script.

Comment: `for k in config_dict: subprocess.call([config_dict[k]], shell=True)` but the first way is better - in both cases you are iterating over the dict. `config_dict[k]` just returns the value, which you have already assigned to `v` in the first case

Comment: `items()` just returns the key:value pairs as a list of tuples.